# Два инстанса npm на одной машине

Tags: node.js, администрирование, npm

Есть Ubuntu 16.04 сервер, на котором развернут NodeJS, npm и Gulp. Хочу сделать отдельный микро-проект на поддомене и использовать для него отдельный чистый конфиг npm, отдельные node-модули, отдельный Gulp и т.д. и т.п. Можно ли так делать и не навредит ли это каким-то образом основному инстансу?

Comment: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: @etki, а можно ответом, чем именно `nvm` поможет и в чем суть?  Я что-то сомневаюсь, что это возможно... Тем более, что мои познания в `NodeJS` пока еще крайне скудны

Comment: Это консольный автоматизатор установки нескольких версий node-окружения (сам node, npm, npx), с которым получится поставить их без каких-либо проблем

Comment: @etki у меня до этого стояла версия ноды 6.14.1, я написал в терминале `nvm install node`, установилась версия 9.11.1. Значит, теперь у меня установлено две разные версии Ноды - 6.14.1 и 9.11.1. А дальше что делать?

Comment: используете `nvm use <version>`, и после этого в текущей сессии команды node / npm / npx будут вызывать бинари соответствующей версии